# I can't understand HQL joins

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am starting to work with hibernate. I am quite confused about `HQL` joins... they are really different from, say, mySQL joins... In fact if I have two tables like Parking and Auto I would do:

```
select *
from Parking
left join on Parking.pid = Auto.parkingId
```

or something the like. Instead in hibernate I will have a Parking class already linked to Auto, and have all the associations mapped. So the joind would be automatically resolved by hibernate. Anyway I still have the join keyword but in the examples its used in a way I don't understand, usually specifying a property of the object in the from clause... what does it means? What is the SQL equiv of that operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to remember that HQL talks about classes and fields, whereas SQL talks about tables and columns.

And if you specify an association, hibernate will automatically do the joins for you. Imagine a class Library which contains a List of Book. Each book is in one library.

```
@Entity public class Library {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy"library")
  public List<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
  }
  ...
} 

@Entity public class Book {
  @ManyToOne
  public Library getLibrary() {
    return library;
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, you can use hibernate to find a Library object for you, and you don't need to specify any joins. It just knows what to do (although you can often help it improve its performance if you give it more details).

```
Library library = entityManager.find(Library,1);
for (Book book : library.getBooks()) {
  System.out.println("Found book: " + book.toString());
}
```

In my experience, it's possible to get a lot done using hibernate without using "join" at all!

More details on the annotations at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/

Answer (score 2):

Let me try. Here's an example I've already given (take from [here](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/hibernatequery102/?source=archives) )

Imagine the case of an online 
shop which sells shirts. Each shirt model comes in a certain number of available sizes. You want a query to find all the shirt models with sizes over 40. In HQL, the query might be the following :

```
from Shirt shirt
join shirt.availableSizes size
where size.number > 40
```

In other words, you want to get all the objects, but you need the search criteria for some of the joined tables (and I mean join one-to-many - you have a collection of `availableSizes` and you can't reach the `number` property without the join).

**edit**
You can get some more info from [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins). There are some explanations about **implicit** and **explicit** joins. And more important - some fetching strategies (in case you put some connections between you tables as **lazy** but you also want, in some cases, to fetch them immediately). Read it, if you haven't, you might find it useful.

Comment: This way seems that the *classic* join I would do on a relational DB is already done. The only purpose of the join clause in HQL is to select a column of the joined table and put restrictions on it... isn't it?

Comment: @gotch4 - well, not only this. See the edit, there is more explanations in the article I refer to.

Comment: @Danail: Is availableSizes an individual class/table or just a field in shirt?